# Firebase storage - uploaded image, no download url

Tags: firebase, download, upload, storage

I use firebase console to upload a image to Storage.

See below screen shot

[image]

Image preview is not loaded with error: Error loading preview
And I could not find download url under File Location.

Can anyone help what's missing? I'm expecting a download url somewhere.

The rules is default:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Storage API you can try to retrieve the download URL of your file
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl()
which returns a Promise object.
e.g.

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
const imageRef = storage.ref().child('app-icon-48x48.png'); //if any subfolder include it in the path
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
  console.log(url);
} );
```